# Is there a way to affect the position of an img but not the source in an anchor element?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to position an img separately from the source (text) in an anchor element? For instance, in the picture, I want the word "dot" to be aligned further right than the arrow but stay on top of the arrow.

current
[image: example]

what I want
[image: example]

I know I could make them as separated anchors but I want the color of the word to change when you hover on the arrow as well and if they are separate, the a:hover doesn't work together.

I tried changing the position under .left img to be different but it moves the img and the source.

HTML code:

```
    <span class="leftarrow">
        <a href="dot.html">dot<img src="images/leftarrow.png"></a>
    </span>
```

CSS code:

```
.leftarrow {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
}

.leftarrow a{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color:gray;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.leftarrow a:hover{
    color: black;
}

.leftarrow img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 15px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: wrap the `dot` into a `<span>` or `<div>` for better control,

Second: use a more powerfull display mode (e.g: flex or grid)

here is a sample:

```css
a {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  color: black;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}

div {
  font-size: 32px;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
    <div>dot</div>
    <img src="https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/271/271218.svg" />
 </a>
```

Comment: Thanks @mahdi! I will try this. I just edited my question to clarify. I want the word to stay above the arrow but be shifted to the right so that it is off centered.

Comment: @CamMeyer I updated my snippet. I think it is what you want now.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up just putting dot in a span and then was able to keep the absolute positioning and only affect the left attribute of the span.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using [Pseudo-Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp). It could definitely be more optimized than this though.

```css
a {
margin-left: 100px;
}


span:after {
  content: "";
  background-image:url('https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/271/271218.svg');
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: 30px 30px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left:90px;
  top: 15px;

}
a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
    <span>dot</span>
 </a>
```